# show info main message in parent with primefaces

Tags: java, forms, jsf, primefaces, message

I wanna have just one

```
<p:growl id="messages"/>
```

So i have created one form for the whole project with thepages elements and so on as forms inside the main one, something like this.

```
    <h:form id="mainForm">  
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" for="mainForm"/>   

        <div id="container">
            <div id="banner" >
                <a><img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/logo.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                <ui:insert name="head">
                    <ui:include src="/panels/header.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <ui:insert name="content">
                    <ui:include src="/panels/main.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <ui:insert name="right-sidebar">
                    <ui:include src="/panels/box.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </div>

            <div id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>

        </div>
    </h:form>
```

The problem comes when one of those panels.. (xhtml) files shows a message it is not shown in the growl of the main page.
I have try with for, with global and no luck.

In conclusion: how do i create a p:growl once, to handle all of the messages of my site?

Any suggestion

Thnx in advance

Comment: The problem might be the way the `FacesMessage`s are queued. Within those panels, are you queueing the messages with specific client ids?

Comment: I did it with and without specific client Ids, and still not working in this case i did:
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("mainForm", new FacesMessage(severity, title, msg));
But any change.

Comment: is `mainForm` a component or an `<h:form/>`? I've not seen (or attempted) queuing messages for a form. Use specific components within the form instead

Comment: `and so on as forms inside the main one` Are you nesting forms? You shouldn't do that

Comment: `globalOnly="true"` specifies that you only want to display messages which are not attached to any element id, so you are narrowing it even more.

Comment: I tried with and without globalOnly="true"  and there is no difference, the problem persist, i nested form because i was trying to use just one p:message which it will handle all of the messages in the pages but with no sucess

Answer (score 0):

You should not nest multiple forms (as you sayed you do).

Try to encapsulate the

```
<p:growl .../>
```

Tag in one Form before the other includes and just leave the autoUpdate attribute as true. Remove the globalOnly attribute as this will effect, that only FacesMessages for component id "null" will be displayed:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">  
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/> 
</h:form>  

    <div id="container">
        <div id="banner" >
            <a><img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/logo.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>
            <ui:insert name="head">
                <ui:include src="/panels/header.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>

        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">
                <ui:include src="/panels/main.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <ui:insert name="right-sidebar">
                <ui:include src="/panels/box.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>

    </div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i manage it to make it work, was something simple, as I suspected it, i had to update the growl which handle the messages.

```
     <h:form id="mainForm">  
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>   
     </h:form>
```

like, check the update method.

```
  <p:commandButton  id="logBut" value="Login" actionListener="#{loginBean.loginUser}" update=":mainForm:message" icon="ui-icon-carat-1-e"/>
```

that it works with or without nested forms.